# Facebook login returning nothing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I looked all over and I can't seem to find the solution to this. I am trying to implement Facebook login to my website and I am having one hell of a time doing so.

I have implemented the Facebook graph api and I have the login part built in but I can't get anything to return from it to handle it.

You can see what I mean on < phiride.com > (I don't know if that's bad netiquette to post the url on this website, if so sorry!)

I used the code given to get a return -->

```
<script>
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
</script>
```

Absolutely nothing is printed to the screen and I can't find anyway to handle the information. I'm sure this is a simple beginner mistake but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the html and script via their website.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button

Comment: Yes I did, I can generate the log-in space but I can't handle any data from it.

Comment: So you want to be able to gather the users details. [This may be more of what you are looking for](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1#permissions).  FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});

Comment: Alright That is all cool and I understand what is going on with that code but the part that the API doesn't seem to talk about and what I'm trying to figure out is how to handle that exception to get the data. Like is is token.data('email') or something? I tried console.log(email); and all sorts of variations just to see if I can print the data and I can't.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do in order to make API calls work:

- Initialize the JavaScript SDK
- Authorize the user

**Initialize the JavaScript SDK**

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

**Authorize the user**

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       console.log('Your Email: ' + response.email);
     }, {scope: 'email'});
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
});
```

Only call `FB.login` on user interaction (on click) to make sure it does not get blocked by the browser - it has to get called AFTER `FB.init` too. You can also check if a user is already authorized by using `FB.getLoginStatus` right after FB.init.

Sources:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Comment: This was a very elaborate and in depth response, Thank you! But I am having an issue with handling the data from a log-in with my website. Once you're positive that they're signed in, how can you handle their information. Any advice on how to handle their email, (hopefully MD5) password, names etc. would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can´t get their password, of course. you can get the email with the "email" scope (see FB.login in the docs) and with the /me endpoint. same with the name of the user, it will be in the /me endpoint too.

Comment: You have been incredibly helpful but the answer to my question is most likely a lot simpler than the answers you've been giving. I just need to see the code that will request for example and email and allow me to either print it or store it. I keep trying to call and log an email but nothing shows up. If I can see the data print and know where the data is I can handle it from there and use the code to add in any other scope needed. Thank you again!

Comment: /me includes the email already - but only if you added the email permission, and you can´t be sure that everyone got an email. i will change the FB.login call to include the email in the authorization. you MUST authorize the user for the FB.api call, of course.